# How can i save the JSON and access the objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I am currently working with MQTT pub/sub and will receive a message whenever a topic publishes and the message I receive is and may vary with topics.

The JSON received is assigned to message

```js
client.on('message', function (topic, message)
 { cmd: 'set', reqid: 'string', objects: [ { type: 'devices', data: ["tring"], execution: {"command": "OnOff", "params": { "on": true }} } ] }
```

I want to save the JSON in a variable and access the objects from it.

[image]

The JSON is string and when ever i try to access its objects like ( message.cmd ) it says "undefined"

Comment: You need to use JSON.parse()

Comment: if you check @anush online with your json string in http://json.parser.online.fr/ . You get that its your function issue with brackets

Comment: update your function : - client.on('message', function (topic, message)
 { 
{cmd: 'set', reqid: 'string', objects: [ { type: 'devices', data: ["tring"], execution: {"command": "OnOff", "params": { "on": true }} } ] 
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var data = JSON.parse(strData);  // strData is what you got in response. 
console.log(data);
```

**Update**

I have checked your JSON and I found that issue is in quotes in JSON. If you can update your response that just set res as this.

```
{
  "cmd":"set",
  "reqid":"string",
  "objects":[
    {
      "type":"devices",
      "data":["string"],
    "execution":{
      "command":"OnOff",
      "params":{
      "on":true
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Then you don't need to `parse` data also. you can direct access object it self.

```
console.log("Parse data is :::",txt.cmd);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sachin Shah ..Thanks for the quick replay, Yeah I got that but the issue is I am unable to access the objects... when i try "console.log(data.cmd)" its giving "undefined"   and here's the data i got "{ cmd: 'set', reqid: 'string', objects: [ { type: 'devices', data: ["tring"], execution: {"command": "OnOff", "params": { "on": true }} } ] }"

Answer (score 0):

To convert a JSON string into an object use

```
var recObject = JSON.parse(stringJson);
```

To convert it back into a string use

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(recObject);
```

Comment: you can use recObject.cmd to get the cmd

Answer (score 0):

By the help of `JSON.parse()`:

```
var data = JSON.parse(stringData);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hi ....I am not able to access the objects console.log(data) gives "{ cmd: 'set', reqid: 'string', objects: [ { type: 'devices', data: ["tring"], execution: {"command": "OnOff", "params": { "on": true }} } ] }"    but "console.log(data.cmd)"  is undefined

Comment: Please check with data["cmd"]